# Does corrosion of iron increase its mass?

Tags: mass

Does corrosion of a sample of iron increases or decreases its mass? I think that the mass will increase because of additional oxygen atoms.

Comment: Well, look at it this way: are any particles (atomic or subatomic, or photons) given off as the iron oxidises?  Do those particles take away more energy (aka mass, thanks to Einstein) than the added mass of the oxygen atoms?

Comment: possibly very related :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLm4sgnNsfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following reactions take place :

$O_2 + 4 e^− + 2 H_2O → 4 OH^−$
$Fe → Fe^{2+} + 2 e^-$
$4 Fe^{2+} + O_2 → 4 Fe^{3+} + 2 O^{2−}$
$Fe^{2+} + 2 H_2O ⇌  Fe(OH)_2 + 2 H^+$
$Fe^{3+} + 3 H_2O ⇌ Fe(OH)_3 + 3 H^+$
$Fe(OH)_2 ⇌ FeO +  H_2O$
$Fe(OH)_3 ⇌ FeO(OH) +  H_2O$
$2 FeO(OH) ⇌ Fe_2O_3 +  H_2O$
(source : Wikipedia )

Now since initially only $Fe$ was present and finally its **oxides** are present in the sample, there is **definitely** an increase in the mass of the *sample*.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, rust expands, so it increases in mass during the rusting process (in a closed system), but it also has lower density AFAIK.